# Should I correct quotes with spelling errors or leave them be?

Tags: quotes

I'm quoting a soldier's diary for a historical paper, and it has many spelling errors. Should I correct them for the reader, or leave them be? If I do correct them, how would I do it?

For example:

"The guards search every natave that goes into Menila."

"He hasent layed down his arms yet an we are expecting trouble every day."

Comment: **sic** >> intentionally so written — **used after a printed word or passage to indicate that it is intended exactly as printed or to indicate that it exactly reproduces an original**
//_said he seed [sic] it all._ [Merriam-Webster]

Comment: This is your choice. You _don't_ want a bespattering of _[sic]_'s so a summarising caveat, either [original spellings etc] or [corrected for spellings etc] can be used.

Comment: As for the question of whether to correct, this is covered by various style guides, e.g. [AP](https://writingexplained.org/ap-style/ap-style-quotes) says don't.